# probability and birth and death process.

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a question from the text bellow.
The author talks about a simple birth and death process.
where production-lose is applied.
however, there is something I could not comprehend.
He says something confuses me he was talking about equilibrium
and then he explains this equation.

$$k_R Prob(m)=\gamma_R (m+1)Prob(m+1)$$

1. How come the L.H.S and R.H.S are equal?.

Does he mean it is true when we consider a lose term in the R.H.S?

or he means in the deterministic model and the system is at the steady state
and adding one does not make any difference?

I hope my question is clear?

Thank you in advance.

The text is here.. Sorry, I cannot it as an image.

\

In the simplest possible model of constitutive gene expression (Fig. 1A), a transcript is produced at a constant rate $k_R$ and destroyed in a first-order reaction with rate constant $γ_R$. If the total number of a particular transcript m is large, the kinetics can be approximated by the following deterministic differential equation:
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=k_R-\gamma_R m.$$

This approximation breaks down in cells when the copy numbers of transcripts are small. For example the average transcript copy numbers of the constitutive housekeeping genes MDN1, KAP104, and DOA1 in budding yeast are 6.1, 4.9, and 2.6, respectively (7). These low copy numbers suggest a probabilistic reformulation of Eq. [1]. In the constitutive expression model, transcript births and deaths occur as uncorrelated events, such that in any short time interval, dt, the probability of one transcript production is kR·dt, and the probability of one transcript degradation is γR·m·dt. For equilibrium to be possible, the probability of having m transcripts, Prob(m), and producing another must be equal to the probability of having (m+1) transcripts, Prob(m+1) and having one degrade. In other words,
$$kR·Prob(m) = γR·(m+1)·Prob(m+1)$$

for any m, which is only possible if the copy number distribution follows a Poisson distribution (8).
.

Comment: In a given time interval of length $dt$, $k_R\text{Prob}(m)dt$ is the probability that there were $m$ transcripts, and another was produced. While $\gamma_R(m+1)\text{Prob}(m+1)dt$ is the probability that there were $m+1$ transcripts and one degraded. If the population is in equilibrium, new transcripts must be born at the same rate old ones degrade, so they equate these two. I think having $m+1$ instead of $m$ is a mistake, making $m+\frac 12$ the equilibrium population point instead of $m$. But it is a fairly trivial one.

Comment: Thank you Paul, can I look at it as I have x population at time t then at time t+dt I have two choices: 1. I can be at state x if no birth or 2. if I have x+1 at time t then I need to lose 1 to return to state x at time t+dt. but ur point about the equilibrium I did not get it tbh. Thank again Paul

Comment: Not quite: you do not have two separate choices. You have two different things going on at the same time. A new copy may be created, and an old copy may degrade. There is a certain probability that one may occur, and a probability that the other may occur. Maybe they could both occur, maybe only one or the other occurs, maybe neither one occurs. All we know is because it is in equilibrium, the overall rates of new copies and degrades must be the same in the long term.

Comment: Thank you. Nice and clear 
many thanks again